# Why can't I add new records to all my access database tables?

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

I just wonder why I can't add new records to all my access database tables. I am using the html form and classic ASP code shown below to write to one of my tables and it works perfectly.

HTML FORM CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="empresas.asp">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Código:</td>
<td><input name="custid"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Empresa:</td>
<td><input name="compname"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Teléfono:</td>
<td><input name="contname"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input name="address"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Descripción:</td>
<td><input name="descr"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add New">
<input type="reset" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

CLASSIC ASP DOCUMENT CODE:

```
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/administracion1.mdb"

sql="INSERT INTO empresas (codigo,nombre,"
sql=sql & "telefono,email,descripcion)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("custid") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("compname") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("contname") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("address") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("descr") & "')"

on error resume next
conn.Execute sql,recaffected
if err<>0 then
  Response.Write("No update permissions!")
else
  Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
end if
conn.close
%>
```

These work perfectly. However, when trying to do the same using another very similar form and table I get the message shown on the ASP code ("No update permissions!"), I really don't understand why.

Comment: You must disable the "on error..." to see the details or post the wrong code instead the correct one. And caution with SQL injection!

Comment: Thanks. I hope it works.

Comment: If you can write to some tables but not others within the same mdb/accdb file then I would guess that the issue lies within the database rather that with your Classic ASP code, which looks OK to me. As Antonio says though, you should comment out "on error resume next" - you might get an error message which offers you some clues.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the actual error by using:

Response.Write("No update permissions! - " & Err.Description)